# Проверка наличии значения в таблице mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть значение переменной которое парсируеться каждый раз при обновлении страницы. Это значение сохраняеться в таблицу mysql phpmyadmin. При обновлении страницы значение добавляеться снова. То есть при двух обновлениях значение удваиваеться в таблице. Нужно написать так чтобы он проверял значение в таблице и если оно уже там есть то не добавлять.

Вот код который я сумел написать, но он не работает:

```
$connection=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","база данных", "пароль","пользователь");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result =  mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM таблица");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
if ($row[' column '] == $переменная с значением для сохранения) {
echo "Values are same";
}
else {
    mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO таблицы (значение1,значение2,значение3) VALUES ('$переменная с значением для сохранения1','$переменная с значением для сохранения2','$переменная с значением для сохранения3')");

}
}

 mysqli_close($con123);
```

Answer (score 1):

> которое парсируеться

парсится

> добавляеться, удваиваеться

http://tsya.ru

> Нужно написать так чтобы он проверял значение в таблице и если оно уже там есть то не добавлять.

В первую очередь обычно проблему решают на уровне БД: добавляют уникальный индекс. На уровне приложения вы почти все сделали:

```
$found = false;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row[' column '] == $переменная с значением для сохранения) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!$found) {
    // добавляем запись
}
```